# Messages not showing up in SQS

Tags: amazon-sqs

I have the following code in a lambda:

```
  entries = [
        {
            "Id": str(index),
            "MessageAttributes": {},
            "MessageBody": json.dumps(
                to_format(record=record, id_names=IDENTIFIERS, attr_names=ATTRIBUTES, source_names=SOURCE_METADATA)
            ),
            "MessageDeduplicationId": record["message_composite_key"],
            "MessageGroupId": sqs_group_id
        } for index, record in enumerate(records)
    ]
    logger.info(f"{len(entries)} batch entries built")
    queue_url = environ["SQS_QUEUE_URL"]
    try:

        # iterate over entries in batches of 10
        for batch in [entries[index:index + sqs_batch_limit] for index in range(0, len(entries), sqs_batch_limit)]:
            logger.info(f"Sending batch of {len(batch)} records to sqs...")
            sqs.send_message_batch(
                QueueUrl=queue_url,
                Entries=batch
            )
            logger.info("**Sent batch of records to sqs successful**")
```

and it seems like it's erroring out because of this message:

```
 'InvalidParameterValue', 'Message': 'The request include parameter that is not valid for this queue type'
```

I can't find documentation for htis anywhere. Any idea what is giong on?

Comment: Is this queue a FIFO Queue, or a Standard Queue?

Comment: ahhh, nvm, it's a standard queue and I was passing things unintended for a standard queue. Why don't standard queues take dedup keys?

Comment: Because of SQS's distributed architecture, standard queues have a transactions-per-second (TPS) capacity that is [officially documented as *"nearly unlimited."*](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-quotas.html) The cost in time and resources for deduplication is one of several reasons why FIFO queues have substantially lower throughput than standard queues (300 TPS per API action).

Answer (score 6):

`MessageDeduplicationId` and `MessageGroupId` cannot be used in a Standard Queue, according to the [SQS reference](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/APIReference/API_SendMessage.html).